# assign local variable which is inside th:each to global variable thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have page that includes two dropdown. In second dropdown I want to select "beamer" and assign it to "ssection" variable to calculate results. Is there any way to get selected dropdown item to assign it global variable in . How can I do ?

I am trying to get ssection to redirect to page after clicking calculate button.

```
    <body>
<div th:replace="~{fragments/header :: header}"></div>
<div  th:with="sssection='',beamtype=${typest}" >
    <div class="container" style="width: 400px;">
        <div class="row mt-5 align-items-center">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="text-center" style="max-height: 300px; width: 400px;">
                    <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" th:src="@{'/assets/img/beamimg/' + ${sbeam}}"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col mt-4">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle w-100" type="button"
                                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                    aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded="false"
                                    id="dropdownMenu1" th:text="${typest != null} ? ${typest} : 'Select Section Type'">
                                Select Section Type
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"
                                style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 150px;">
                                <li th:each="section : ${stsection}">
                                    <form
                                            method="post"
                                            role="form"
                                            th:action="@{'/workspace/beamdetail/' + ${selectedbeam} + '/' + ${section}}"
                                    >
                                        <button class="dropdown-item" type="submit" th:value="${section}"
                                                th:text="${section}" onclick="showGenre1(this)"></button>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col mt-4">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle w-100" type="button"
                                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                    aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded="false"
                                    id="dropdownMenu2">
                                Select Steel Section
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pre-scrollable w-100" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2"
                                style="overflow-y: auto; max-height: 150px;">
                                <li th:each="beamer : ${beamsteel}">
                                    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" th:value="${beamer}"
                                            th:text="${beamer}" onclick="showGenre2(this)"></button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <form
                    method="post"
                    role="form"
                    th:action="@{'/workspace/selectbeam/' + ${typest} +'/' + ${ssection}}"
                    th:object="${calbeamr}"
            >
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row mt-3" th:switch="${sbeam}">
                        <div class="input-group" th:case="b1.png" style="width: 250px; padding: 5px;">
                            <label class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 5px;">P</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="b1" name="b1" type="text" autocomplete="off"
                                   style="padding: 5px;">
                            <label class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 5px">(kN)</label>
                            <label class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 5px">L</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="b1l" name="b1l" type="text" autocomplete="off"
                                   style="padding: 5px;">
                            <label class="input-group-addon" style="padding: 5px">(m)</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary mb-2" type="submit">Calculate</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer th:replace="~{fragments/footer :: footer}"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't assign global variables in Thymeleaf.  Best you can do is use `th:with` which is scoped to the tags inside it.  Thymeleaf also doesn't know anything about which dropdown is selected.  Once the HTML is output, you'll need JavaScript if you want to interact with user selections without submitting it to the server again.

Answer (score 0):

I have handled the situation by two dropdowns one of which submit form to load second one and reload the page. I have tried not to use jquery.